# Keep sudo open when running script

Tags: sudo, session, timeout

I have a relatively simple script to run:

```
sudo dosomething1
sudo dosomething2
sudo dosomething3
```

Now, all these different commands take a while. As those are commands run by `sudo` I have to provide the `sudo` password. Sometimes though I am asked to enter the `sudo` password for the second and third command again, when their previous command takes too long. I assume this is caused due to `sudo` only being active during a certain timeout. Is there any way to keep it open during the entire session of one run like the above without the timeout constraint?

Comment: did you try to use your command in one line (with the `&&` operator)? so it would be `sudo dosomething1 && sudo dosomething2 && sudo dosomething3`, and it would ask you the password just at 1rst time without edit `sudo` config files

Comment: remove the `sudo`s from inside the script; instead run the script using `sudo`

Comment: Try ``sudo -- sh -c "dosomething1 && dosomething2 && dosomething3"``

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver and @ Carl. So the solution is to have it processed as "one single" set of commands and not as multiple single commands.